# datetimepicker defaulting to current timestamp

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker and need it do default to a given time. Not the default time which is the current timestamp

HTML, php, and javascript is as follows:

```
<div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append">
<input data-format="hh:mm:ss" type="text" name="adjtimeout" value="<?php echo $adjtimeout; ?>"></input>
<span class="add-on">
  <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>
 </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false
  , pickSeconds: false
  , pick12HourFormat: true
  , useCurrent: false
//      ,  hour: 13,
//        minute: 15
}).setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

});

Comment: Are you sure the documentation of bootstrap does not cover this topic?

Comment: Wath time ? Current time ?

Comment: I was unable to find this in the documentation.

Comment: @rakwouen, yes it is returning the current time.